# Vehicle Odometry Probability Density Function Parameter Question (Bicycle Model)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am constantly updating vehicle position and heading from odometry data from the vehicle (yaw rate, steering angle, vehicle speed). I have the algorithm down, with a nice plot that **ALMOST** matches that of GPS reference, *yet there is a constant heading angle drift that is building up.*

Currently, updated x, y and heading (theta) are calculated by...

$$ x' = x + (v/\omega)(\sin (\theta + \omega\Delta t) - \sin \theta) $$
$$ y' = y + (v/\omega)(- \cos (\theta + \omega\Delta t) + \cos \theta) $$
$$ \theta' = \omega\Delta t + \gamma\Delta t $$

which are odometry update equations from the bicycle model.

I have no problem calculating the first two (x' and y') but **I am struggling to calculate $ \gamma $ term that can be described by the following,**

$$ \gamma = \epsilon_{\alpha v^2+\beta\omega^2}   $$

where the notation with $\epsilon$ denotes normal distribution with zero mean and variance $b^2$ given by the density function given below, and the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ denotes robot noise that I would be playing with to fit the curve:

$$ \epsilon_{b^2}(a) = {{1/\sqrt(2\pi b^2)} * e^{-a^2/2b^2}} $$

**My question is, what do I plug in to a & b of the above equation if I am trying to gamma? I am confused since gamma term involves distribution for both v and w. Thanks for the help!**

Comment: Integration is prone to drift errors.  A small offset in the measurement of the rate integrates to a linearly increasing error.  The usual prescription is to get a position measurement once in a while and to update your position model with it.  You need to get the position measurement often enough that the errors do not build up unacceptably between them.  If you think of Fourier analyzing your error in terms of $\sin (\omega t)$ this integrates to $-\frac 1{\omega} \cos (\omega t)$.  As $\omega \to 0$ the error goes to infinity.

Comment: @RossMillikan I appreciate your feedback but I don't think that answers my question. I am aware that sporadically updating my reference position values would kill the errors but the goal of this project is to use odometry info only.

Comment: That is why I didn't make it an answer.  I don't think you will get an answer without periodic position updates.  The noise in the velocity measurement is too large so the error will build up unacceptably without them.  I suggest you analyze the error in your measurements and see how it propagates into position error.  You can improve things somewhat by using the corrections you make from position measurements to evaluate the drift, but unless the drift is very steady it can't make it perfect.

Comment: Can you post the code for your model?